# How to programmatically change one RecyclerView item style?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I've got this `RecyclerView`, it's showing a list of persons with their names, phones and birthday.

I want to change the color of the item if the person's birthday is today, but I want to know if I should do the verification and change on my `RecyclerView's` adapter inside the `OnBindViewHolder` method, or if I should do it inside my activity calling my `LinearLayoutManager` or calling the item using the `RecyclerView.getChildAt()` method.

Should I go whit the first option, using the `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES** . Should you choose to make changes in the `onBindViewHolder()`. 
We'll take a sample:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedsViewHolder feedViewHolder, int i)
{       

    if(d1.feeds.get(i).getFeedContentType().equals("b-day")) // <-- Pointing to the List that contains value, and checks if it equals to a sample string
    {
        feedViewHolder.n1.setText("Birthday"); // <-- if it equals, party time :D , and sets text to the corresponding TextView in the RecyclerView
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with this method :)